# My reaction role bot write the embed message but the reaction doesn't add role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My reaction role bot send an embed message with reaction but when you choose a reaction the role is not attribute

I have this code
index.js :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]}, {partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION", "MANAGE_ROLES"] })
require("dotenv").config();

const prefix = "!";

const fs = require("fs");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands/").filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("bot online");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === "reactionrole") {
        client.commands.get("reactionrole").execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

reactionrole.js :

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = "889233386781151232";
        const maths = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Maths");
        const mathsExpertes = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Maths expertes");
        const nsi = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "NSI");
        const physique = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Physique");
        const svt = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "SVT");
        const artsPlastique = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Arts Plastiques");

        const mathsEmoji = '';
        const mathsExpertesEmoji = '';
        const nsiEmoji = '';
        const physiqueEmoji = '';
        const svtEmoji = '';
        const artsPlastiquesEmoji = '';

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#e42643")
            .setTitle("Selection des matière")
            .setDescription("Choisis tes matières en cliquant sur la reaction qui correspond\n\n"
                + `${mathsEmoji} : Maths\n`
                + `${mathsExpertesEmoji} : Maths Expertes\n`
                + `${nsiEmoji} : NSI\n`
                + `${physiqueEmoji} : Physique\n`
                + `${svtEmoji} : SVT\n`
                + `${artsPlastiquesEmoji} : Arts Plastiques\n`);

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
        messageEmbed.react(mathsEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(mathsExpertesEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(nsiEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(physiqueEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(svtEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(artsPlastiquesEmoji);

        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === mathsEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(maths);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === mathsExpertesEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(mathsExpertes);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === nsiEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(nsi);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === physiqueEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(physique);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === svtEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(svt);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === artsPlastiquesEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(artsPlastique);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
        client.on("messageReactionRemove", async(reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === mathsEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(maths);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === mathsExpertesEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(mathsExpertes);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === nsiEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(nsi);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === physiqueEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(physique);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === svtEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(svt);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === artsPlastiquesEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(artsPlastique);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and when launching the command I have this which appears as an error

**(node:8760) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)**

can you help me please

and I know this question has already been asked but I didn't understand the answer or it was not clear

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty self-explaining. Somewhere in your Code you're using this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
   // Some code
});
```

But since **Discord.js v13** you have to use `messageCreate` instead of `message`:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
   // Some code
});
```

Comment: I didn't know where to put messageCreate !

Comment: But now i know it

Comment: this doesn't work I've try it but it doesn't work i haven't error message but the role aren't assigned